# Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'RadTextBox'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a little problem I have here a RadTextBox that should receive float values in the db the date Type is also float so now if i want to bind the RadTextBox there is always this strange error

> *Error    4   Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to
>   'Telerik.Web.UI.RadTextBox'*

Do I need to parse or  something else ?

My code

```
private void bindData()
{
    this.cbActive.Checked = this.paramBR.GetActive();
    this.rtbCode.Text = this.paramBR.Code;
    this.rtbDescription.Text = this.paramBR.Description;
    this.rtbHourlyRate = this.paramBR.HourlyRate;
}

BillingRate br = ctx.BillingRate.Where(yx => yx.BillingRateId == this.paramBR.BillingRateId).FirstOrDefault();
if (br == null)
{
    br = new BillingRate();
    newEntity = true;
}
br.Code = this.rtbCode.Text;
br.Description = this.rtbDescription.Text;
br.SetActive(this.cbActive.Checked);
br.HourlyRate = this.rtbHourlyRate.Text;
br.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
br.CreatedBy = this.User.UserId;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text.aspx) property in your last line and use [`.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hfd35ad.aspx) method for casting `double` to `string`.

```
this.rtbHourlyRate.Text = this.paramBR.HourlyRate.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks for your fast response but now I'm getting a Cannot implicit convert type 'double'to 'string' can you help me with that too ?

Comment: @laserbear Updated. Just use `.ToString()` method.

Comment: THX allot for your effort !!

Comment: can I ask you just some one little question more , for the same context ?

Comment: I have update my question so now I'm saving all the things but why is there know again   Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double' I have already tried it with toString but this time its not working why ?

Comment: br.HourlyRate = this.rtbHourlyRate.Text

Comment: Try this `br.HourlyRate = Double.Parse(this.rtbHourlyRate.Text);`

Answer (score 2):

Use `RadTextBox.Text` property to assign text. Also convert `double` value to `string` when assigning it to textbox:

```
// you missed that here
this.rtbHourlyRate.Text = this.paramBR.HourlyRate.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks for your fast response but now I'm getting a Cannot implicit convert type 'double'to 'string' can you help me with that too ?

Comment: @laserbear already updated answer with that part. Just call `ToString()` on your double value

Comment: WOW THX allot for your effort !!

Comment: @laserbear Don't forget to accept whichever answer you feel is most appropriate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your last line should read:

```
this.rtbHourlyRate.Text = this.paramBR.HourlyRate.ToString();
```

not

```
this.rtbHourlyRate = this.paramBR.HourlyRate;
```

You weren't assigning to the text property of the RadTextBox but to the RadTextBox itself. You should also convert the double to a string in the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
this.rtbHourlyRate = this.paramBR.HourlyRate;
```

To:

```
this.rtbHourlyRate.Text= this.paramBR.HourlyRate;
```